# Java Regex get all numbers

Tags: java, regex

I need to retrieve all numbers from a String, example :

```java
"a: 1 | b=2 ; c=3.2 / d=4,2"
```

I want get this result :

- 1
- 2
- 3.2
- 4,2

So, i don't know how to say that in Regex on Java.

Actually, i have this :

```java
(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)
```

He split letter and number (but the double value is not respected), and the result is :

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 2 (problem)
- 4
- 2 (problem)

Can you help me ?

Thanks :D

Comment: Could you share the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // Test
        String s = "a: 1 | b=2 ; c=3.2 / d=4,2";
        showNumbers(s);
    }

    static void showNumbers(String s) {
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\d[\\d,.]*");
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
2
3.2
4,2
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use a capturing group with a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
[a-z][:=]\h*(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)
```

**Explanation**

- `[a-z]` Word boundary, match a char a-z
- `[:=]` Match either `:` or `=`
- `\h*` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part with either `.` or `,`
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VZTFp3/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/JQCaPN)

For example

```
String regex = "[a-z][:=]\\h*(\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)?)";
String string = "a: 1 | b=2 ; c=3.2 / d=4,2";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
1
2
3.2
4,2
```

Comment: Actually this is the result : [,  | ,  ; ,  / , ] 
:/

Comment: ++ but you may remove starting `\\b`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
/\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?/g
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/whPcdL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You may jsut need a regex like `(\d(?:[.,]\d)?)` that

- find a digit
- evently dot/comma + other digit after

The multi-digit version is `(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)`

```
String value = "a: 1 | b=2 ; c=3.2 / d=4,2";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d(?:[.,]\\d)?)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
//        1
//        2
//        3.2
//        4,2
```